# How do I solve the "out of disk space" error thrown by GRUB?

Tags: grub2

Trying to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD, I get the following error:

```
error : out of disk space
grub> rescue
```

When I try grub commands it doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue faced users said issue was with BIOS (bios not having the correct disk size) I saw something else in reference to the out of disk error - apparently if your partition/data is above 137gb some BIOS's won't access it. And used [BURG](https://launchpad.net/burg)
 as solution, here is the reference link for same http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420427(I have not used it personally but found useful)

Comment: One more link for reference <http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688468>

Comment: Please, could you add more details to your answer (e.g. what is BURG and how it should be used to solve the problem)? Posting links is good, but [great answers should not rely just on them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Thanks! @AndreaCorbellini I have got your point and edited the post  to my best level.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a motherboard or HDD issue.

The jumper on your HDD needs to be set master (or not limited to a certain ammount)

And yes some bios will only detect or boot up to certain amount but ubuntu may still see your drive size. Check your bios size limit and change the jumper on your drive.